# Como Introducir eficientemente código html en js

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente `JS`:

```js
<script>
var targetDiv = document.getElementById('content');
var htmlContent = '';

function populateData(idTipe) {

  switch (idTipe) {
    case 'VideoIni':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';

        break;
      }
    case 'VideoS':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';

        break;
      }
    case 'ColabIni':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';

        break;
      }
    case 'Colab':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';

        break;
      }
    case 'Shop':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba</p> <img src="../img/carlos2.png" alt="">';

        break;
      }
    case 'Profile':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style="text-align:center">Texto de prueba numero 2</p>  <img src="../img/prueba.png" alt="">';
        break;
      }
    case 'Contact':
      {
        htmlContent = '<p style=text-align:center>Texto de prueba</p> <img src=../img/prueba.png alt=">';
        break;
      }
    default:
      console.log('Lo lamentamos, por el momento no disponemos de ' + idTipe + '.');
      break;

  }
  targetDiv.innerHTML = htmlContent;
} 
</script>
```

Me gustaría poner una plantilla en `html` dentro de la variable `htmlcontent`, a la hora de hacerlo me han surgido varias dudas.

La primera, se puede crear un archivo `html` con la plantilla y que la variable `htmlcontent` llame al fichero? por llamar quiero decir como el funcionamiento de un `include` que muestre el código y lo ejecute pero sin re direcciones, como si lo hubiese escrito todo dentro de la variable (la idea es reducir el código todo lo que se pueda).

La segunda, si no se pudiera, para poner todo el código `html` dentro de la variable `htmlcontent`, cómo sería la mejor forma?

Se que en principio las comillas "" aceptan saltos de lineas pero luego me da problemas con el resto del código ya que también las usa.

Pongo por aquí la url a la plantilla para que podáis ver el código que quiero introducir en la variable `htmlcontent`:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4Mm5R

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la etiqueta `<template>` para no guardar el html dentro de una variable de js:

> El elemento HTML `<template>` es un mecanismo para mantener el contenido
> HTML del lado del cliente que no se renderiza cuando se carga una
> página, pero que posteriormente puede ser instanciado durante el
> tiempo de ejecución empleando JavaScript.

```html
<template>
<p> este fragmento de html no se renderiza,
pero puede ser usado luego. </p>
</template>
<p> este fragmento sí se renderiza </p>
```

> Se que en principio las comillas "" aceptan saltos de lineas pero
> luego me da problemas con el resto del código ya que también las usa

Puedes usar el caracter: **`** para crear cadenas multilínea:

```js
var textoLargo = `

este est un texto con saltos de línea

que  no necesita usar concatenación. Se pueden usar "texto entre comillas", o texto entre 'texto entre comillas simples'

`

console.log(textoLargo)
```

Comment: pero no es solo para texto es para código html, si pongo el código html de la pagina que puse donde esta mi código de la variable htmlcontent no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de cosas, yo soy fan de los arreglos / objetos, ayudan a simplificar el código y es muy fácil agregar más opciones.

```js
// Definir los tipos disponibles > Identificador: [ texto-a-mostrar, nombre-de-imagen ]
const types = {
    VideoIni: [ 'Texto VideoIni', 'imagen-video-ini.png' ],
    VideoS: [ 'Texto VideoS', 'imagen-video-s.png' ],
    ColabIni: [ 'Texto ColabIni', 'imagen-colab-ini.png' ],
    Colab: [ 'Texto Colab', 'imagen-colab.png' ],
    Shop: [ 'Texto Shop', 'imagen-shop.png' ],
    Profile: [ 'Texto Profile', 'imagen-profile.png' ],
    Contact: [ 'Texto Contact', 'imagen-contact.png' ],
    DEFAULT__: [ 'Tipo no disponible', 'imagen-not.png' ]
};
let targetDiv = document.getElementById('content');
let htmlContent = '';

function populateData(idTipe) {
  // Obtienes datos si el tipo está definido, o asignas DEFAULT__
  let data = types[idTipe] || types['DEFAULT__'];
  // Actualizas con plantillas de texto
  targetDiv.innerHTML = `
      <p style="text-align:center">${data[0]}</p>
      <img src="../img/${data[1]}" alt="${idTipe}">
  `;
} 
// Probando con un tipo que no está definido
populateData('ColabX');
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```